# Confusion about negligible and non-negligible functions in crypthography

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I am learning basic cryptography from Coursera's cryptography I course and am a bit confused about the negligible and non-negligible function epsilon and how it relates to the predictability of pseudo random generators (PRG).

In the video lecture, it says that the PRG (as a function called "G") is predictable if:

If there exists such an algorithm A and there exists an i; 1 <= i <= n-1 (n is the length of the string defined in the universe U: {0,1}^n)

such that:

Probability of the algorithm being able to predict the next bit (i+1) is >= 1/2 + epsilon

where epsilon can be a number like 1/(2^30).

The thing that I am confused about is the examples he gave of what is negligible and what is not negligible.

In particular, here is the example that the lecture said is negligible:

e(lambda) = 1/(2^lambda) is negligible.

From what I am able to understand, if I plug in 1 for lambda, I get e(1)=1/2 and in the inequality I gave above, the right side adds to 1 (1/2 + 1/2), so that means that the probability of the PRG being predictable is impossible?

Note: lambda is supposed to be a polynomial, but it is still a bit confusing as to what it means in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of an algorithm correctly predicting the next bit in a perfectly random sequence, is exactly 0.5 - because there are two potential outcomes of equal likelihood and it's selecting one of them. So for a perfectly random generator, any next-bit-predicting algorithm will have a probability of correct prediction, of exactly 0.5.

That means, if you have a NBP algorithm that is able to give better predictions than perfect randomness, it is necessarily not perfectly random any more - so it is pseudorandom by definition.

If you have an algorithm that has accuracy of *less* than 0.5, then you are able to flip all bits, and its accuracy is then *more* than 0.5; this allows us to reduce the consideration to only cases where the probability of correct prediction P is above 0.5. Then you can simply define epsilon to be eps' = (P - 0.5)/2. From there you can plug values into the equation and solve, so:

0.5 + eps' = 0.5 + (P - 0.5)/2 = 0.5 - 0.25 + P/2 = 0.25 + P/2 =< P/2 + P/2 =< P

and you're done.